# elastic search + jdk

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-8

I am trying to write one web app with Ruby on Rails and using elasticsearch there for searching. I know that elastic search internally calls java api's and for that matter of the fact, it needs jdk to be installed on the machine. So, I downloaded java from official oracle website. File 'jdk-8u101-linux-x64.tar.gz' from "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html".

After the completion of download, I extracted the files from the gz package as suggested by the official documentation but java is still not installed on my machine. I am sure that I am missing something but what?

```
Installation of the 64-bit JDK on Linux Platforms

This procedure installs the Java Development Kit (JDK) for 64-bit Linux, using an archive binary file (.tar.gz).

These instructions use the following file:

jdk-8uversion-linux-x64.tar.gz

Download the file.

Before the file can be downloaded, you must accept the license agreement. The archive binary can be installed by anyone (not only root users), in any location that you can write to. However, only the root user can install the JDK into the system location.

Change directory to the location where you would like the JDK to be installed, then move the .tar.gz archive binary to the current directory.

Unpack the tarball and install the JDK.

% tar zxvf jdk-8uversion-linux-x64.tar.gz

The Java Development Kit files are installed in a directory called jdk1.8.0_version in the current directory.

Delete the .tar.gz file if you want to save disk space.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the full path to `jdk1.8.0_version`
2. Edit `/etc/profile`
3. Add `export JAVA_HOME="paste there the path that you copied"`
4. Add `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`
5. Restart your terminal and rerun

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path where you have untar the jdk-8uversion-linux-x64.tar.gz file